# wifi connection lost from time to time on a Dell Inspiron 1520

Tags: wireless, inspiron

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 installed on a Dell Inspiron 1520. I got my wifi working but the connection to the router drops from time to time. I couldn't figure out yet what's causing the drop.

The connection doesn't recover automatically. Instead, if I disable the wifi and enable it back, it reconnects immediately.

With the other computers in the house I don't have this problem, so it assume it's something related to the OS or the drivers.

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong? 
I can provide log files or configurations, if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell which Wifi-card you have? You can type sudo lshw -class network in a terminal to find out.

Comment: @speter Sorry it took so long. Here's the name of the wifi card:

`product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN  
vendor: Broadcom Corporation`

Comment: Thanks lonut. I have the same problem but with an Intel Centrino advanced-n 6205. I think it is most likely a bug in 12.10's network manager.

Comment: In the meantime I found an advice that I should disable the IPv6 for it. I did so and, for the moment, it doesn't disconnect anymore. Anyway, I'll post here if I will still encounter the problem.

Comment: I, in the meantime, have installed the wireless backports from the USC, which seems to solve the problem.